# Updating XML Tags Attributes Values in .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have an xml string like that

```
<root>
Am trying <br id="9"/>to reorder the <br id="5"/>break 
lines <br id="10"/> attributes value
</root>
```

Any Way to change attribute value of XML BR tag ID attribute to be in sequence
like this

```
<root>
Am trying <br id="1"/>to reorder the <br id="2"/>break 
lines <br id="3"/> attributes value
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example using [LINQ TO XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

```
Dim doc as XElement = <root>
Am trying <br id="9"/>to reorder the <br id="5"/>break 
lines <br id="10"/> attributes value
</root>

Dim index as Integer = 0

For Each br In doc.<br>
    index += 1
    br.@id = index
Next
```

This results in the following output

```
<root>
Am trying <br id="1" />to reorder the <br id="2" />break 
lines <br id="3" /> attributes value
</root>
```

Also, here's an example using a [LAMBDA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253%28VS.90%29.aspx) expression.

```
doc.<br>.ToList().ForEach(Sub(br) 
                index += 1 
                br.@id = index 
              End Sub)
```

Comment: `doc.Elements("br")` could be simplified to `doc.<br>`.

Comment: @MarkHurd good point. I'll update the sample to reflect this.